# How to have python functions and classes available system-wide with an easy `import` statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

## Introduction

I thought I'd try my hand at making a python module to make some of my libraries and functions available system-wide.
Google and StackExchange provide ample "solutions" and how-toos. But for some reason none of them seem to work for me. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong. But after days of trial & error I've decided to show you guys what I have and let you point out the obvious error to me ;-) Your help is much appreciated.

## What I have

My GitHub project directory contains this tree:

```
$ tree /tmp/mausy5043-common-python
/tmp/mausy5043-common-python
├── docs
├── gitforcepull
├── LICENSE
├── mausy5043funcs
│   └── __init__.py
├── mausy5043libs
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── libdaemon3.py
│   └── libsmart3.py
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── tests
```

`libsmart3.py` is a python script that offers a `class SmartDisk():`. Both `__init__.py` scripts are empty. `libdaemon3.py` is a script that contains another class. It has the same problem but I'll use the `libsmart3` module as an example here.

I install this project as follows:

```
$ sudo python3 setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/mausy5043libs
copying mausy5043libs/libdaemon3.py -> build/lib/mausy5043libs
copying mausy5043libs/libsmart3.py -> build/lib/mausy5043libs
running install_lib
copying build/lib/mausy5043libs/libsmart3.py -> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mausy5043libs
copying build/lib/mausy5043libs/libdaemon3.py -> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mausy5043libs
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mausy5043libs/libsmart3.py to libsmart3.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mausy5043libs/libdaemon3.py to libdaemon3.cpython-34.pyc
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mausy5043_common_python-0.1dev.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mausy5043_common_python-0.1dev.egg-info
```

## What doesn't work

Now I want to use this class `SmartDisk()` in another python script. To do this I expected (was hoping) that I would be able to import the class directly -- thanks to the presence of the `__init__py` -- thus:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mausy5043libs import SmartDisk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'SmartDisk'
>>>
```

**OR**

```
>>> from libsmart3 import SmartDisk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'libsmart3'
>>>
```

## How I don't want it to work

What **does** work is this:

`>>> from mausy5043libs.libsmart3 import SmartDisk`

but this is not how it was advertised (ref: http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html )

## What else did I try

I've tried to add `import libsmart3` in `mausy5043libs/__init__.py`. Doesn't work.

I've added `from libsmart3 import SmartDisk` in `mausy5043libs/__init__py`. No joy.

I've added an empty `__init__.py` in the project root under the assumption that python needs this. Didn't help.

**EDIT**
changes made: to `mausy5043libs/__init__py` as suggested by @user2357112

```
$ cat mausy5043libs/__init__.py
from .libsmart3 import SmartDisk 
$ sudo python3 setup.py install 
[... output removed ...] 
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mausy5043libs import SmartDisk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'SmartDisk'
```

**EDIT 2** : It turns out the solution provided by @user2357112 *does* indeed work. There was, obviously, a small oversight on my part. In `setup.py` the entry `mausy5043libs/__init__` was missing in the `py_modules` list.

Comment: What do you mean "*this is not how it was advertised*"?

Comment: @MattDMo On various websites it is suggested that the class could be imported directly from `libsmart3` or `mausy5043libs` (I forget which) instead of having to give the entire path `mausy5043libs.libsmart3` to the class.

Comment: @Mausy5043: You misread those websites, or those websites just suck, or both.

Comment: ref: http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how it works with the setup you have. If you have `ClassName` stored in `moduledir/somefile.py` you're going to have to import it `from moduledir.somefile import ClassName`.

Comment: @Mausy5043: Yeah, you misread it. Check the first two code snippets and the surrounding text under "What goes in `__init__.py`?".

Comment: You dropped a dot in `from .libsmart3 import SmartDisk`. This is Python 3; relative imports must be explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You completely misread the sources you were working off of. If you want to be able to import `SmartDisk` directly from the `mausy5043libs` package, then `mausy5043libs/__init__.py` needs to import `SmartDisk`:

```
# in mausy5043libs/__init__.py
from .libsmart3 import SmartDisk
```

Then users of the package can import it the way you want:

```
# in code that wants to use SmartDisk
from mausy5043libs import SmartDisk
```

The article you linked includes this information under "What goes in `__init__.py`?", although they use pre-Python 3 implicit relative import syntax.

Comment: I think I already did try that. But, I'll try it (again) just to be sure. That `.` is new though.

Comment: @Mausy5043: You're reading a Python 2 article, so the relative import syntax is different.

Comment: Unfortunately your suggested solution is not working for me.

Comment: @Mausy5043: Well, you have some other issue, then. Maybe `mausy5043libs` isn't coming from the files you think it is, or maybe you have a typo you're not showing us. Go through the usual "am I running the code I think I am" checklist: Try `import mausy5043libs; print(mausy5043libs.__file__)` and see if it shows what you expected. If it does, check the files in that directory and see if they match what you think they should look like. Try deleting the .pyc files to force Python to recompile the .py files.

Comment: I notice `__init__.py` is missing from `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mausy5043libs/` ... Going to figure that out.

Comment: Well that did it. `__init__.py` was not listed in `setup.py`. After adding it and re-installing this answer worked. Thanks @user2357112 !

Comment: Learn something new every day. Thanks. Clearly Python3 is heavily under-blogged. ;-)